# Java download to target (target can't be found) and 0 byte file download

Tags: java, file, download

I am trying to use this code below on button click to download a file and save it to a location. However, it always returns that the target destination could not be found. It seems to not create the directories needed. Do I have to tell it to do that or is it supposed to do it for me? Below is the function I'm using:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
            try {
                //ProgressBar/Install
                System.out.println("FILELOCATION:\n----------");
                System.out.println(filelocation.getText());
                String URL_LOCATION = "http://www.futureretrogaming.tk/gamefiles/ProfessorPhys.iso";
                String LOCAL_FILE = (filelocation.getText() + "\\ProfessorPhys\\");
                System.out.println("LOCALFILE:\n-------");
                System.out.println(LOCAL_FILE);
                URL website = new URL(URL_LOCATION);
                ReadableByteChannel rbc = Channels.newChannel(website.openStream());
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(LOCAL_FILE+"\\ProfessorPhys.iso\\");
                fos.getChannel().transferFrom(rbc, 0, Long.MAX_VALUE);
                System.out.println("--------\nDone Downloading\n---------");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e);
            }
```

**EDIT :**
If I manually create the directories it downloads (kinda). Is there anyway to check if the directory already exists and if it doesn't create it? Also, when it downloads, it just makes the file it doesn't download it as the downloaded file that shows up is 0 bytes. How can I fix this?

**EDIT:**
I have created the below code that checks if the directory exist and if it does not, creates it. This does work however, the only thing that still does not work is the download. I have included that problem in the title now.

For anyone who wants the code that works it is below:

```
        String LOCAL_FILE = (filelocation.getText() + "\\ProfessorPhys\\");
        File localfile = new File(LOCAL_FILE);
        if (localfile.exists()) {
            System.out.println("Directory exists!");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Directory doesn't exist! Creating...");
            localfile.mkdir();
            if (localfile.exists())
                System.out.println("Directory created!");
        }
```

Comment: are you behind a proxy?

Comment: also, the URL opens but is in fact a 0 Bytes long. Are you sure that is the right URL? Have you tried using a different (like google.de or some other file you _KNOW_ exists)

Comment: Its my file on my server so I don't see why it wouldn't work but I will double check the URL. I also edited my question a bit.

Comment: @AngeloNeuschitzer I am not behind a proxy. I also edited my question.

Comment: You're right I am now showing that the file is -0 bytes as well. I will reupload the file and try again. I will post back with more details.

Comment: Okay, when I from my connection open that url it is a 0 Byte File. If you store it, you will get a 0 Byte file. That is not a bug. If the file is NOT 0 Bytes from YOUR browser, then please explain why is that.

Comment: `... .iso\\ ` better `... .iso` even it is seems to work. `mkdirs()` you sought. `fos.close()`.

Comment: That was the problem. Off to trying to get it to work with the swing worker lol.

Comment: What was the problem? If you have solved you question please post your answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code worked for me:

```
//ProgressBar/Install
                System.out.println("FILELOCATION:\n----------");
                System.out.println(flocation);
                String URL_LOCATION = "http://www.futureretrogaming.tk/gamefiles/ProfessorPhys.iso";
                String LOCAL_FILE = (flocation + "\\ProfessorPhys\\");
                File localfile = new File(LOCAL_FILE);
                if (localfile.exists()) {
                    System.out.println("Directory exists!");
                }
                else {
                    System.out.println("Directory doesn't exist! Creating...");
                    localfile.mkdir();
                    if (localfile.exists())
                        System.out.println("Directory created!");
                }
                System.out.println("LOCALFILE:\n-------");
                System.out.println(LOCAL_FILE);
                URL website = new URL(URL_LOCATION);
                ReadableByteChannel rbc = Channels.newChannel(website.openStream());
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(LOCAL_FILE+"\\ProfessorPhys.iso\\");
                fos.getChannel().transferFrom(rbc, 0, Long.MAX_VALUE);
                System.out.println("--------\nDone Downloading\n---------");
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using the `transferFrom()` method as a one-liner. However, I think you should check whether more data is available. From the [API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html#transferFrom%28java.nio.channels.ReadableByteChannel,%20long,%20long%29):

> An attempt is made to read up to count bytes from the source channel and write them to this channel's file starting at the given position. An invocation of this method may or may not transfer all of the requested bytes; whether or not it does so depends upon the natures and states of the channels. Fewer than the requested number of bytes will be transferred if the source channel has fewer than count bytes remaining, or if the source channel is non-blocking and has fewer than count bytes immediately available in its input buffer.

A similar question was also [posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7651528/java-nio-transferfrom-until-end-of-stream) that may help you.